# Connection Problem for the Confluent Heun Equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

Consider the Confluent Heun Equation (CHE) written in its non-symmetrical canonical form, i.e,
$$y''(z)+\left(4p+\frac{\gamma}{z}+\frac{\delta}{z-1}\right)y'(z)+\left(\frac{4p\alpha z-\sigma}{z(z-1)}\right)y(z)=0,$$
which has two regular singular points at $z=0$ and  at $z=1$, and one irregular singularity at $z=\infty$.

As someone that does not work in the field, it is hard for me to know for sure how much is known about the two-point connection problem between the two regular singularities, i.e., about the relations between local solutions at $z=0$ and $z=1$.

So far, I could only find the work by R. Schäfke and D. Schmidt, *The Connection Problem for General Linear Ordinary Differential Equations at Two Regular Singular Points with Applications in the Theory of Special Functions*, (1980) SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis 11(5). In this paper, an asymptotic formula for the connection coefficients is given.

Does anyone know of some other sources where the connection coefficients between solutions of the CHE at $z=0$ and $z=1$ are found explicitly?

Comment: It would be helpful -for potential answerers- to clearly specify your problem: ie to explicitly write down your CHE and the two local solutions you are trying to connect together with possible restrictions ( continuity, order of differentiability, etc). Stated as it is, it rather looks like a class of problems than a specific problem itself.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou Thanks for your comment, it was very pertinent.